confusion in understanding proof of why equality hold related to plancherel theorem and fourier transform
If $\hat{F_0} \in L^2(0, \infty)$ and $F(x+iy)= \int_{0}^{\infty} \hat{F_0}( \xi )e^{2\pi i \xi z} d \xi$. Then, How? by Plancherel's theorem, it follows that
$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert F(x+iy)\rvert^2 dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \lvert \hat{F_0}(\xi)\rvert^2 e^{-4 \pi \xi y} d \xi $.
Here, $F$ is in the Hardy space of $\mathbb{R}_+^2$.

Define the function $$F(z)=\int\limits_0^\infty \widehat{F}_0(\xi)e^{2\pi i\xi z}d\xi ,\quad z=x+iy,\ y\ge 0$$
This function is holomorphic in the upper half plane.
For any fixed $y>0$ we have
$$F(x+iy)=\int\limits_0^\infty [ \widehat{F}_0(\xi)e^{-2\pi \xi y}]\,e^{2\pi i\xi x }d\xi$$
The above formula means that the function $x\mapsto F(x+iy)$ is the inverse Fourier transform of the
function $\mathbb{R}\ni \xi\mapsto  \widehat{F}_0(\xi)e^{-2\pi \xi y}.$
Applying the Plancherel theorem gives
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty |F(x+iy)|^2\,dx=\int\limits_0^\infty |\widehat{F}_0(\xi)|^2e^{-4\pi \xi y}\,d\xi$$
The integral on the right hand side is restricted to $[0,\infty)$ as the function $\widehat{F}_0$ vanishes on the negative half-axis.
Remark It may be clearer to assume  $F_0\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ so that $\widehat{F}_0$ vanishes on the negative half-axis. So formally $\widehat{F}_0$ is defined on the whole real line.

It is possible to add more clarification. I am still confused thank you.
